# Facebook Game Development - storing items in (which) database?

Tags: database, facebook

I'd like to develop a small Facebook game with some graphics involved (not that many). Within that game, the users will be able to buy/sell certain items and I wonder WHERE I can save those items/virtual money ...? Does Facebook offer me a database I can use?

Comment: I think there is a better site for this: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to host your own database for your game. Facebook just provides the frontend, it's up to you to manage and run the backend services.